# how to stop my jquery animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#road').pan({ fps: 30, speed: 9 });

        $('#city2').pan({ fps: 30, speed: 2 });

        $('#city3').pan({ fps: 30, speed: 5 });

        $('#sky').pan({ fps: 30, speed: 0.5 });

        $('#plane1').sprite({ fps: 10, no_of_frames: 8 });

        $('#stop').click(function () {
            $('#body').stop();
            $('#city2').stop();
            $('#city3').stop();
            $('#sky').stop();
            $('#road').stop();
        });

    });
});
```

this is my code, can you tell me how to stop my city and road from moving? i try to use stop but it doesn't work.

Comment: Tip: jquery allows multiple selectors. Use: `$("#body, #city2, #city3, #sky, #road").stop();` to simplify your code.

Comment: okay. but this doesn't solve my problem here. know how to stop my animation?

Comment: What does `pan()` do, and where does it come from ?

Comment: pan is to make my image[background] moving to left or right so that it feels like my plane1 is walking.

Comment: http://addyosmani.com/blog/jquery-sprite-animation/
here is the explanation

Comment: http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/sprites/demo.html

here is the example. so how to stop the city, plane and sky from moving ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
.stop(true)
```

Code:

```
    $('#stop').click(function () {
        $('#body').stop(true);
        $('#city2').stop(true);
        $('#city3').stop(true);
        $('#sky').stop(true);
        $('#road').stop(true);
    });
```

Comment: Looking at your code, you are asking an element with `ID` to stop. That can't make sense because no motion was called on it.

Comment: Something like this would stop the animation from continuing. `$('#road').stop(true).slideToggle( 1000 );`

Comment: what do you mean no motion was called on it?? so what can i do so that when i click stop button. the city, road and can stop?